# how to run a testng.xml file from a maven project in command prompt

Tags: java, maven, selenium, testng

To run testng xml as a suite we need lib and bin folder to be used in class path
bu since i am using maven project i don't have such folders how to run testng xml in maven project

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using Maven, maven manages your classpath for you. So you dont need any lib or bin folder like ant.

To run your `testng.xml` suite file using Maven, here's what you need to do.

1. Add a test scope dependency to latest released version of TestNG. Refer [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng/6.11)
2. Refer to the surefire plugin documentation [here](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/testng.html), to learn how to add an entry of surefire plugin to your pom file.
3. Now from a command prompt just run `mvn clean test` to trigger your tests.

Comment: Thanks. but maven build is very ugly with log of logs.so wanted to run testng.xml only